# angularJS - splitting up ng-repeat into multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the third question I have posted today so forgive me but I am just running into things I can't seem to figure out.

Here is my code for angular:

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
.constant('API', 'http://appsdev.pccportal.com:8080/ecar/api')
.controller('task', taskData)

function taskData($scope, $http, API) {
  $http.get( API + '/tasks' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.mainTask = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

And some simple stripped down HTML:

```
    <ul>
      <li class="view1" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> <strong>CAR ID:</strong> {{ task['CAR ID'] }} </li>
      <br>
      <li class="view1" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> <strong>Title:</strong> {{task['Project Title']}} </li>
      <br>
      <li class="view1" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> <strong>Amount:</strong> ${{task.Amount}} </li>
      <br>

      <li class="view1" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> <strong>Status:</strong> {{task.Status}} </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is what that returns:

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

How can I split up ng-repeat and allow me to separate the values (if I'm saying that right) that are being fed in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move your `ng-repeat` up to the `<ul>`. This way, you have a separate `<ul>` for each `task` in your `mainTask.Tasks` list.

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">
  <li class="view1" > <strong>CAR ID:</strong> {{ task['CAR ID'] }} </li>
  <br>
  <li class="view1"> <strong>Title:</strong> {{task['Project Title']}} </li>
  <br>
  <li class="view1"> <strong>Amount:</strong> ${{task.Amount}} </li>
  <br>

  <li class="view1"> <strong>Status:</strong> {{task.Status}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh.....Still kinda new to angular so this is a learning process. I just learned something new though which I probably should have known. It worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also use ng-repeat-start="..." and ng-repeat-end for situations more complex than this. https://thinkster.io/egghead/ng-repeat-start

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you question well, you just need to apply the `ng-repeat` "higher" in your html : You want here to either get "a list" for each car (1) or "an element" for each car (2).

(1) is :

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">
    <li class="view"><strong>CAR ID:</strong> {{ task['CAR ID'] }}</li>
    <li class="view"> <strong>Title:    </strong> {{task['Project Title']}} </li>
    <li class="view"> <strong>Amount:</strong> ${{task.Amount}} </li>
    <li class="view"> <strong>Status:</strong> {{task.Status}} </li>
</ul>
```

(2) is :

```
<ul>
    <li class="view" ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">
        <strong>CAR ID:</strong> {{ task['CAR ID'] }}<br>
        <strong>Title:</strong> {{task['Project Title']}}<br>
        <strong>Amount:</strong> ${{task.Amount}} <br>
        <strong>Status:</strong> {{task.Status}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

(2) is a bit better because semantically, you are showing a list of cars so all the info of a car should be in a `<li>` element, but that's really a detail.